My C# application on Visual Studio enters break mode for some reason even with exceptions are handled (I think)
I've been working on a large C# application designed to perform various tests on multiple serial devices. The goal is for the application to run continuously, executing around 10 tests periodically and uploading the results to a database. Everything was progressing smoothly until, out of nowhere, the program started entering break mode in less than a day of runtime.
The issue seems to stem from a hardware problem: the COM ports disappear after some time, and this has been happening more frequently lately. However, I had already implemented exception handling to manage this issue. The program is supposed to catch the exception when the COM ports disappear and continue running. And for a while, it does just that—catching the error and keeping the tests running. But after some time, it just enters break mode without any apparent reason.
The strange part is that the exception handling works for a while but eventually gives up, and I'm not sure why. Could there be a limit on how many times an exception can be triggered in the IDE before it forces break mode? Or is there a time limit after which the application can no longer recover from the exception?
Any insights from the community would be greatly appreciated!
I uploaded the tail end of the debug log. Most of the log is redundant. There are errors where it doesn't get access to the com port, I handle the exception by logging the e.message and closing the port. This way of handling works fine but suddenly it enters break mode and I don't show any specific location in the code where it decided to break. So I'm kind of blind when it comes to debugging this issue.
I also attached the screenshot of the IDE when this happened. YOu can see that a certain call is blocked. Can anybody please shed some light on what's happening here?
IDE Screenshot
2024-10-08 01:32:13.3191 | INFO | 2024-10-08T01:28:44**********COM94**********2**********CE24140001D********************10/8/2024 1:32:13 AM**********Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)**********
 \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | Exception Could not find file 'COM90'.    for port COM90 \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | stack 1: Void HandleException(System.Exception) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | stack 2: Boolean SendCommandWithoutQuery(System.String) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | stack 3: Boolean CANDown() \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | stack 4: Boolean PenguinPostStartupCommands(Int32) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:32.9861 | ERROR | stack 5: Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | Exception Could not find file 'COM90'.    for port COM90 \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | stack 1: Void HandleException(System.Exception) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | stack 2: Boolean SendCommandWithoutQuery(System.String) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | stack 3: Boolean WifiDown() \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | stack 4: Boolean PenguinPostStartupCommands(Int32) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:33.0243 | ERROR | stack 5: Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean) \n
2024-10-08 01:32:51.9409 | INFO | 2024-10-08T01:28:44**********COM94**********2**********CE24140001D********************10/8/2024 1:32:51 AM**********Void PingLTETest(System.String, Int32)**********
 \n
2024-10-08 01:32:54.0729 | INFO | ./LTEping
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ #  \n
2024-10-08 01:32:56.2052 | INFO | ./LTEping
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ #  \n
2024-10-08 01:32:58.3388 | INFO | ./LTEping
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ # 
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~ #  \n
2024-10-08 01:32:59.8681 | INFO | 2024-10-08T01:28:44**********COM94**********2**********CE24140001D********************10/8/2024 1:32:59 AM**********Void eMMCTest(System.String, Int32)**********
 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:03.4663 | INFO | 2024-10-08T01:28:44**********COM94**********2**********CE24140001D********************10/8/2024 1:33:03 AM**********Void LTETransmitTest(System.String, Int32)**********
 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:04.5915 | INFO | ./LTEtransmit
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~  \n
2024-10-08 01:33:05.7169 | INFO | ./LTEtransmit
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~  \n
2024-10-08 01:33:06.8420 | INFO | ./LTEtransmit
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
microcom: can't create '/var/lock/LCK..ttyS3': File exists
APCBPGN2101-CE24140001D ~  \n
2024-10-08 01:33:08.2868 | INFO | time taken for LTETransmit test4 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:18.3677 | INFO | 2024-10-08T01:28:44**********COM74**********3**********CE241400075********************10/8/2024 1:33:18 AM**********Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)**********
 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | Exception Could not find file 'COM90'.    for port COM90 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | stack 1: Void HandleException(System.Exception) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | stack 2: Boolean SendCommandWithoutQuery(System.String) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | stack 3: Boolean CANDown() \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | stack 4: Boolean PenguinPostStartupCommands(Int32) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.0991 | ERROR | stack 5: Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | Exception Could not find file 'COM90'.    for port COM90 \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | stack 1: Void HandleException(System.Exception) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | stack 2: Boolean SendCommandWithoutQuery(System.String) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | stack 3: Boolean WifiDown() \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | stack 4: Boolean PenguinPostStartupCommands(Int32) \n
2024-10-08 01:33:41.1358 | ERROR | stack 5: Void RebootCheck(System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean) \n

Implemented a log file using the Nlog library to find out what's happening.
The log file doesn't show anything unusual. There are errors because one of the serial ports fails but the program continues its execution as expected, thanks to the error handling method. Not sure why it stops doing this after some time.
The code doesn't have any parallel architecture implemented. It's a round-robin scenario. Tests are performed on each serial device sequentially.



If you look under Debug > Windows > Exception settings. Is anything checked for it to break when encountering those exceptions? Also, in the VS options dialog, Debugging > General there's a checkbox Check When Exceptions Cross AppDomain or Managed / Native Boundary. That sounds like it might be useful to look at.

I checked my other account and din't see my question. I figured it was deemed ridiculous and was not posted ..lol ..  Thank you. I'll check those and get back to you.

Is this what you are talking about (attached pic)? These are the settings. I din't change anything

I unchecked all the exceptions ... It stilled happened .. Not sure how to fix it .. Checked the diagnostics ..  Process memory and cup utilization seems to be where they were when I start the application. Any idea what could have cause this? Attached screenshot of the latest failure
